# Inserting a row at a specific position?

Tags: sqlite

So I created a recipe database, and just now I've noticed I forgot to add an ingredient to the second recipe. The order of ingredients is obviously important here, so even if I add it now to the end of the table, it will still be the last when I `SELECT` the second recipe, when it should be the second ingredient.

Is there any way I can insert it in a specific position, or am I doomed and will have to create an `index` column specifying the order of the ingredients?

NOTE: This is a junction table, so there's no primary key here, thus I can't insert it using a specific primary key value.

**EDIT:** Basically I have three tables: `Recipe`, `Ingredient`, and `RecipeIngredient` many-to-many junction table.

Here's the `RecipeIngredient` junction table structure:

```
RecipeId: FK
IngredientId: FK
Quantity: REAL
UOM: TEXT
Notes: TEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

The rules of the [First normal form (1NF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) are strict on this:

- There's no top-to-bottom ordering to the rows.

Meaning there is no way, in a proper database schema, that a record can be "missing at a certain position".

You are indeed "doomed" and

> will have to create an index column specifying the order of the ingredients

Comment: Lol. I figured as much. I'm already creating the index column. Now the question is if it's best to start the numbering from 0 or 1... Is there common practice for something like this?

Comment: *That* you actually have power over. It's your design. If you want to print out the values for a user, starting at 1 will save you the trouble of adding 1 every time.

Comment: I won't be printing the value to the user, but I'll rather be using it with a Java `List<>`. So in this case I guess it would be more convenient to start at 0, no?

Comment: It really doesn't matter at that point. This is honestly trivial. But if you just can't decide, let me help you: pick 0.

Answer (score 0):

can you show the table structure?
It is difficult to insert a row in specific position without primary key.

Comment: I've edited my question and added the table structure.